# WAMP Admin login does not work, redirected to frontend

Tags: admin, backend

I recently copied over my live site along with database to my WAMP folder and now every time I try to get to the Backend, it redirects me to the homepage.  I'm curious if there is something in the database that I have to change.  I had to rewrite the core_config_data /base_url in order to get it to stop redirecting to the live site when I typed Localhost and I'm curious if it's an entry in my database that is causing it to reroute to the local Frontend.  I've tried localhost/admin localhost/index.php/admin and others.  Let me know if any code would help answer the question.

Comment: Have you flushed your local cache

Comment: How would I flush local cache without access to admin section?

Comment: go to the folder where the magento installation is, then go to var/cache and delete all of its contents

Comment: Right, I knew that.  Yes I've done that and I still get the same problem.

Comment: It might be a cookie issue see:http://rhogue.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/magento-admin-page-redirect-loop/

Comment: It can also be an SSL issue see:http://store.ivvy.ru/blog/magentossl/

Comment: IS your cookie path set in backend? you can see this in core_config_data table if path is set or not, may be this issue is related to cookie path is not set properly.

Comment: I'm not seeing any cookie variable written in my core_config_data Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being redirected, the question is, does magento anything or is it the apache.

## Apache

1. check whether the index.php is called (just put a die in it and check whether the redirect still occurs)
2. check your `.htaccess` for any unwanted redirects
3. Check your VHost settings

## Magento

1. check your `app/etc/local.xml` what the admin path is in the node `admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName`
2. check for a admin url in `core_config_data` or the `local.xml` for the nodes `admin/url/use_custom` (has to be 1) and `admin/url/custom` for the url

Comment: Ok, so my frontName is `<![CDATA[admin]]>` and I can't find an admin URL in `core_config_data` or in `admin/url/use_custom` in `local.xml`.  I think this might be the problem, but I'm curious as to how to fix it.  Can I add those nodes in the `local.xml` and it will update?

Comment: If there is nothing, then there is a fallback to the secure/unsecure base url

Comment: Did you check whether the redirect is from magento or apache?

Answer (score 2):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Tried that, used 127.0.0.1/admin and it didn't work. It gives me a 503 error.  127.0.0.1/ localhost/ and localhost/admin all send me back to 127.0.0.1/

Comment: Have you checked the maintenance flag ?

Comment: I found maintanence.flag.bak in my main folder, should I delete this?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make virtual host entry in your host file. you can find that file at `Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` 
Open this file in notepad.

Make a new entry

> 127.0.0.1       localhost.com

Now instead of 127.0.0.1 use localhost.com (or any other name that you specify)

Comment: I already have that set up, both 127.0.0.1 and localhost go to my WAMP server, the problem is trying to get to the admin section of the site.  If I do localhost/admin, it goes back to the frontend homepage, if I do 127.0.0.1/admin, it gives me an error page.